Sending credentials to subdomain API using XHR
I am currently trying to send images to an API on a subdomain, but it is failing.
In devtools I can see there is a CORS error relating to a redirect on Preflight:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/v1/dashboard/images/upload.php' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

The redirect is caused by lack of credentials even though I have withCredentials on my xhr object:
let endpoint = form.action,
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', endpoint);
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', ({loaded, total}) => {
    ... stuff here ...
});

let data = new FormData(form);
xhr.send(data);

My API has these headers set in the Nginx config:
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://example.com" always;
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";

Other APIs across the site work fine but use fetch rather than XHR - the reason for using XHR for this request is I want to feedback to the user upload progress, which I understand isn't a feature of fetch?

UPDATE:
This morning I removed the auth checks from my API endpoint - the XHR works fine and I can see the progress increment as I'd expect in DevTools.
So the issue is just how to pass the credentials cross domain on Preflight.
As I mentioned before, everything works fine with fetch requests - so I'm guessing XHR needs something more than withCredentials to work?

MORE DETAILS
The payload is image/jpeg being sent via a multipart/form-data form.

I'll delete that, I totally missed the redirect. However, the redirect seems be the problem; where would it be coming from? I mean, for an XHR in general a redirect doesn't really do anything (by itself; the client code can look at it I guess).

Yea it does look like fetch() is strangely not implementing this; it's a very commonly-requested feature.

The redirect is happening because creds aren't getting passed, so my API is redirecting to a error page (something I know I have to change another time). I'm obviously missing something but no search I've done shows me anything obvious that I'm not already doing.

Yeah - the lack of progress surprised me :) hence turning to turn of the millenium technology.

Where is it redirecting to? You're POSTing to a pretty normal-looking URL. I don't know, maybe it's nginx and not php. Well, good look, and sorry for the boneheaded comment.

No problem - I'm not new here :D the functionality is pretty normal, I didn't think I'd still be looking at this at 1 in the morning. I'm going to leave it to fresh eyes in the morning...

Your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header allows from https://example.com but your api is api.example.com

Isn't that normal? My API config is allowing connections from the non-api domain. Also this config works for fetch requests.
